# Problem uploading R package to repository generated using R package "drat"

Tags: r, github, drat

I want to upload the R package `BOLTSSIRR` to a repository generated using the R package `drat`. `BOLTSSIRR` is not my own package, but I need to upload it to a drat repository, because my package uses the `BOLTSSIRR` package and I want to upload my package to CRAN.

I did manage to upload the R package to `drat`, but it seems in the wrong directory. Here is the package: https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat

After listing `BOLTSSIRR` under `Suggests:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file of my package and adding `Additional_repositories: https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat` to the DESCRIPTION file as well, I ran `R CMD check --as-cran` on my package, but I got the following:

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ...Warning: unable to access index for repository https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Suggests or Enhances not in mainstream repositories:
  BOLTSSIRR
Availability using Additional_repositories specification:
  BOLTSSIRR   no   ?
  ?            ?   https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat
Additional repositories with no packages:
  https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat
```

I'm not really familiar with GitHub. A step-by-step instruction would be greatly appreciated, but any other help as well!

Comment: `drat` author here.  It looks like you need to take a look at the (many) tutorials for setting up GitHub Pages.  GitHub lets you server over http / https from there, and that is what `drat` uses.  But you need to enable that at the GitHub repo you created.

Comment: Also it looks like you installed _your package sources_ into a new repository you named `drat`.  That ... is not how it works.  Can you maybe look at the five existing vignettes?  (And one word of caution, we are in the process of defaulting from `gh-pages` branch for serving to directory `docs/` in the main branch).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you very much! I read the vignettes. I deleted the old repo, forked your `drat` page again and now follow the instructions there. In the folder "`myfolder`" I downloaded the drat repo using `git clone https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat.git`.
Then I tried to prune the repo using `drat::pruneRepo(repopath="myfolder/drat")` and then tried to add BOLTSSIRR using 
 `drat::insertPackage("myfolder/BOLTSSIRR_0.1.0.tar.gz", "myfolder/drat/.git")`, but unfortunately these last two commands did not change the files. What could be wrong here?

Comment: This is not a good place for an extended discussion.  (Also note what I just added a week or two ago: see the orange button at the `drat` repo and for this smaller, cleaner, made for forking repo instead:  https://github.com/drat-base/drat.  Note however that is setup for the new code supporting `options("dratBranch"="docs") from `drat` version 1.8.1.1 at `GitHub`.)

Comment: Let's stop this here. Please open an issue ticket at the drat source repo (ie `eddelbuettel/drat` and start by stating your OS amd `drat` version).  All you want is two commands:  initialize a `drat` and insert a package.  Don't the five vignettes show that?

Comment: And I am _of course_ very interested in having you succeed with `drat`. So if you can help me help you make the documentation clearer, I am all for it.  See you over at GitHub...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you! I will open an issue ticket. The vignettes are probably clear, a large part of my problems probably result from me still having some difficulties with the GitHub part..